# Why does VBA macro produce inconsistent results?

Tags: excel, vba

I am encountering a rather baffling situation with my macro. When I run it on exactly the same dataset, occasionally it gives me different outputs. The dataset does not change, the macro does not touch the original data at any moment.

It's purpose to reconcile two rather large sets of data - data encoded in time intervals (from-to) and data encoded in individual days. What I do is that I parse the intervals into days, assign each day entry a comparison key, which contains a flag indicating it is from the interval based data set (H). For the daily data, I just assign a comparison key with a flag that it is from daily dataset (T).

Afterwards I dump both columns with keylines into a single column, one beneath the other and I sort it from largest to smallest. The result looks like this:

```
01/01/2019-stuff-H
01/01/2019-stuff-T
02/01/2019-stuff-H
02/01/2019-stuff-T
etc.
```

Both datasets are fairly large (hundreds of thousands of rows) and the CPU is  taking its time - on my fairly fast PC, it takes around 3 minutes to run all the operations, while on my work laptop, it takes around 15 minutes.

The error comes somewhere during the copy-paste or sorting phase - the dump *sometimes* contains duplicate instances of the same row from the dataset H (intervals parsed to days).

```
01/01/2019-stuff-H
01/01/2019-stuff-H
01/01/2019-stuff-T
02/01/2019-stuff-H
02/01/2019-stuff-T
etc.
```

Funny thing is - I look into the source data and there is no duplication. I look into the parsed interval data, and there is no duplication either. I am unable to reproduce the error when trying to debug the code and runnign it row by row.

The code for that part is very simple:

```
'last row of dump sheet
iLastDump = wsDump.Cells(wsDump.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'last row of parsed interval data
iLastDay = wsDay.Cells(wsDay.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'clear dumpsheet
wsDump.Range(wsDump.Cells(2, 1), wsDump.Cells(iLastDump + 1, 1)).ClearContents

'copy-paste parsed interval data (H-set) to dump sheet
wsDay.Range(wsDay.Cells(2, 10), wsDay.Cells(iLastDay, 10)).Copy (wsDump.Cells(2, 1))

'find new last row of dump sheet
iLastDump = wsDump.Cells(wsDump.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

copy-paste daily data (T-set) into the dump file after the H-set
wsT.Range(wsT.Cells(2, 9), wsT.Cells(iLastT, 9)).Copy (wsDump.Cells(iLastDump + 1, 1))

'find new last row of dump sheet for later calculations
iLastDump = wsDump.Cells(wsDump.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

'sort dumped data
wsDump.Range(wsDump.Cells(1, 1), wsDump.Cells(iLastDump, 1)).Sort key1:=wsDump.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Why do you find the new last row of dump sheet? You just cleared the contents of the column a couple lines earlier - you know the last row will be 2. Aside from that, I can't see why you have duplicates coming through - my initial thought was you weren't clearing the entire column.

Comment: I wrote the code when I was still fiddling if H-set or T-set is going to go in first, so I tried to keep it interchangeable.